# PutMongo 1.3.0 - stuck process

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, jvm, apache-nifi, thread-dump

Any idea because my PutMongo processor gets stuck ¿?

[PutMongo Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwNxO.png)

'nifi dump' attached below

```
[nifi.sh dump][1]
  [1]: https://pastebin.com/raw/b2QDeg0H
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The part of the thread dump that is relevant is this...

```
"Timer-Driven Process Thread-3" Id=56 RUNNABLE  (in native code)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:201)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:424)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteProtocol.execute(WriteProtocol.java:103)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateProtocol.execute(UpdateProtocol.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UpdateProtocol.execute(UpdateProtocol.java:42)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.update(DefaultServerConnection.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$3.executeWriteProtocol(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:475)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$RunExecutor.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:655)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:399)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:515)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.replaceOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:344)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.mongodb.PutMongo.onTrigger(PutMongo.java:175)
```

It is likely blocked due to some kind of networking issue, or unresponsiveness from Mongo.

Ideally the Mongo client used by NiFi would have some kind of timeouts that can be configured and these should be exposed in the processor so we don't block indefinitely.

I am not familiar with Mongo at all though so I can't say how their client works.